# perl one-liner to capture multiple matches in the same line

Tags: python, perl

I want to pull only the numbers out of a file and organized as CSV.

From:

```
  Aa:40, Bint:02 :  Bstring = 0x13   Ccc Num = 52   Dfloat = 164.0
  Aa:40, Bint:03 :  Bstring = 0x1B   Ccc Num = 10   Dfloat = 10.6
  Aa:41, Bint:04 :  Bstring = 0x1A   Ccc Num = 10   Dfloat = 1.6
```

to:

```
40,02,0x13,52,164.0
40,03,0x1B,10,10.6
41,04,0x1A,10,1.6
```

I can do this with Python `re.findall` (shown below)

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print (",".join(re.findall(r'\d+.?\w+', line)))
```

What would be the perl way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are extracting from your strings numeric values.

The way you can do this is with:

```
 m/(\d+)/g;
```

Of course, since you're also including `.` and `x`:

```
 m/(\d[\d\.xA-F]+)/ig;
```

Or as a one liner:

```
perl -nle 'print join ",",  m/(\d[\d\.xA-F]+)/ig;'
```

- `n` is "wrap this in `while ( <> ) {`.

  This means you can pipe `STDIN` or specify a file after it - e.g. `perl -nle 'print join ",",  m/(\d[\d\.xA-F]+)/gi;' somefile` `cat somefile | perl -nle 'print join ",",  m/(\d[\d\.xA-F]+)/gi;'`
- `l` is auto-chomp. It `chomps` linefeeds and re-adds them after a print
- `e` is execute this snippet.

Which effectively makes the above one liner:

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    print join(',', /(\d[\d\.xA-F]+)/gi);
}
```

This gives;

```
40,02,0x13,52,164.0
40,03,0x1,10,10.6
41,04,0x1,10,1.6
```

Which looks like your desired output.

Comment: Your regex currently doesn't handle numbers like 0x1B. Easy fix though.

Comment: Perfect! Good to know the "-l" option.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**`foo.pl`** - direct translation of python snippet</sub>

```
print join (',', m/(\d+.?\w+)/g), "\n" foreach <STDIN>;
```

---

The important thing to notice is the usage of `/g` when looking for matches. This flag will effectivelly say that we are interested in every match present in the string, and not just the first.

Of course, the *one-liner* (that you specifically asked for) can be written as the below, and it might be a little bit more readable to the untrained eye:

```
foreach my $line (<STDIN>) {
  my @data = $line =~ m/(\d+.?\w+)/g);
  print join (',', @data), "\n";
}
```

---

---

```
% cat data.txt             
Aa:40, Bint:02 :  Bstring = 0x13   Ccc Num = 52   Dfloat = 164.0
Aa:40, Bint:03 :  Bstring = 0x1B   Ccc Num = 10   Dfloat = 10.6
Aa:41, Bint:04 :  Bstring = 0x1A   Ccc Num = 10   Dfloat = 1.6
% cat data.txt| perl foo.pl
40,02,0x13,52,164.0
40,03,0x1B,10,10.6
41,04,0x1A,10,1.6
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the use of "join".  It also helps me understand the meaning of the command line option "-l" and "-n".

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
# Declare the regex
my $is_num = qr { 
                    (?: 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+ ) # Match stuff like 0x1B
                    |                    # Or
                    \d+ (?: \.\d+ )?     # 5 or 5.2
                }x; 

chomp(my @data = <DATA>);
for(@data){
   my @new;
   push @new, $1 while /($is_num)/g;
   $_ = join ",", @new;
}

print "$_\n" for @data;

__DATA__
Aa:40, Bint:02 :  Bstring = 0x13   Ccc Num = 52   Dfloat = 164.0
Aa:40, Bint:03 :  Bstring = 0x1B   Ccc Num = 10   Dfloat = 10.6
Aa:41, Bint:04 :  Bstring = 0x1A   Ccc Num = 10   Dfloat = 1.6
```

### Output

```
40,02,0x13,52,164.0
40,03,0x1,10,10.6
41,04,0x1,10,1.6
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it though. Thats the first that came to my mind

Comment: Thanks for the regex -- much tighter than mine.

Answer (score 0):

### Another way

```
# Declare the regex
my $is_num = qr { 
                    (?: 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+ )  # Match stuff like 0x1B
                    |                     # Or
                    \d+ (?: \.\d+ )?      # 5 or 5.2
                }x;  


chomp(my @data = <DATA>);
for(@data){
   s/.*? ($is_num)/$1,/xg;
   s/\W+$//x;
}
print "$_\n" for @data;
```

### Output is the same

```
40,02,0x13,52,164.0
40,03,0x1B,10,10.6
41,04,0x1A,10,1.6
```